# how to get my UIWindow using UIApplication?

Tags: iphone, uiwindow, uiapplication

I have only one window and I tried

```
UIWindow* mWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
```

but this returned nil.

I also tried:

```
UIWindow* mWindow = (UIWindow*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows objectAtIndex:0];
```

But this raised an exception and the app closed, when I tried to print out

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows count]
```

It printed 0

Note: I am putting this in my only view controller's viewDidLoad method and this is completely a new iPad View Based Application so I changed nothing, just trying to get the window

Please help me to get this object

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If your main window is an outlet of your AppDelegate (which should be the case), you may simply use

```
MyAppDelegate* myDelegate = (((MyAppDelegate*) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate));
[myDelegate.window ...]
```

Answer (score 42):

Easiest way is to get the window from the app delegate instead:

```
UIWindow *keyWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];
// Do something with the window now
```

Answer (score 20):

Your application's key window isn't set until `[window makeKeyAndVisible]` gets called in your app delegate.  Your UIViewController is probably being loaded from a NIB before this call.  This explains why `keyWindow` is returning nil.

Luckily, your view controller doesn't need to go through UIApplication to get the window.  You can just do:

```
UIWindow *mWindow = self.view.window;
```

Comment: That's because the view isn't part of the view hierarchy yet. The same is true in viewWillAppear:.

Answer (score 7):

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:0]; // You can also check the count of this to make sure, because if there are no windows it will crash.
```

Answer (score 0):

With iOS 13+ you should use:

```
if let currentScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene,
    let window = currentScene.keyWindow {
    // now window contains the active window
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in multiple ways. I like to use one of the following.

Use this when you need to access it just once.

```swift
if let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.first as UIWindow? {
    // Action
}
```

If you need to access the `UIWindow` multiple times, I would suggest extending a class. I like to extend the `UIViewController`.

```swift
extension UIViewController {
    /// Returns the UIWindow if available.
    public var window: UIWindow? {
        UIApplication.shared.windows.first as UIWindow?
    }
}
```