# iOS : How to handle System Alerts Programmatically inside the App?

Tags: ios, ios8

I am working in a Automation project.
While using Location Service,It is showing an alert. Here alert message is do you want to use Location Service with OK and Cancel button.
Now I don't want to click cancel or Ok button manually.I just want to get system  alert programmatically and and handle the button click.I am using iOS 8 device.Is it possible?

Comment: your question is good

Answer (score 1):

use the time interval for this concept

```
  [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
  // after that add the following line 

  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:4.0 target:self selector:@selector(cancelAlertinAutomatically:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

-(void)cancelAlertinAutomatically:(id)sender
{
NSLog(@"alert View is cancelled here");
[alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: This is a generic question.If I'll use CoreBluetooth framework,during central and peripheral coonnection,It is also showing one alert.The message is "Do you want to Pair" with Cancel and Pair button.Now I want to handle Cancel and Pair button click.

Comment: How do I get alert object?

Comment: you want to get object in which button in click can you give some example for  --> How do I get alert object?

Comment: Only I'll call   [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES]; If and only if I have alert object.Here the question is to get system AlertView or AlertController object first.

Comment: yes correct, [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES]; --> Allow [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:1 animated:YES]; --> Don't allow, ya initially you need to get system alert first , thats why I added the time interval in after 4 sec

Comment: Thanks.Do you have any idea to get System alert object ? I tried with      UIWindow *window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
and   UIWindow *window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows];
to get the alert window.But it's not working.

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3782066/how-to-get-my-uiwindow-using-uiapplication , you can get the windows, if answer is fine please upvote the answer it is useful for future

Answer (score 0):

XCode has tons of automation features, appium or similar ones can take advantage of this and you can do automation.
This could be your search point where you can achieve this